# Errors using MLKit Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I am using the barcode scanner from firebase which is working well, however I always get three errors and I don't know if at some moment they could affect my app

```
Failed to open file '/data/data/com.example.veggystock/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/mlkit_barcode_models/barcode_ssd_mobilenet_v1_dmp25_quant.tflite': No such file or directory
Failed to open file '/data/data/com.example.veggystock/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/mlkit_barcode_models/oned_auto_regressor_mobile.tflite': No such file or directory
Failed to open file '/data/data/com.example.veggystock/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/mlkit_barcode_models/oned_feature_extractor_mobile.tflite': No such file or directory
```

My code to process the image with the UPC is this

```
        scanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                for (barcode in barcodes) {
                    val rawValue = barcode.rawValue.toString()
                    Log.d("RAWVALUE ->>>", rawValue)

                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        val apiCall = getRetrofit(urlBaseUpc).create(ApiService::class.java)
                            .foodDatabase("parser?app_id=$appIdDatabase&app_key=$appKeyDatabase&upc=$rawValue")
                        //&health=vegetarian
                        if (apiCall.isSuccessful) {
                            apiCallBody = apiCall.body()!!
                            if (apiCallBody.listHints.isNotEmpty()) {
                                apiCall2 =
                                    getRetrofit(urlBaseNutrition).create(ApiService::class.java)
                                        .foodAnalysis("nutrition-data?app_id=$appIdNutrition&app_key=$appKeyNutrition&ingr=${apiCallBody.listHints.first().food.id}")
                                //&nutrition-type=cooking
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    if (apiCall2.isSuccessful) {
                                        apiCall2Body = apiCall2.body()!!

                                        if (apiCall2Body.healthLabels.contains("VEGAN")) {
                                            alertBuilder(
                                                R.style.alertDialogPositive,
                                                "${apiCallBody.listHints.first().food.label} is Vegan"
                                            )
                                        } else {
                                            alertBuilder(
                                                R.style.alertDialogNegative,
                                                "${apiCallBody.listHints.first().food.label} is not Vegan"
                                            )
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e("PROBLEM ->>", "API CALL NOT SUCCESFUL")
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                alertNotFound()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("PROBLEM ->>>>>>", "BARCODE NOT RECOGNIZED")
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

These `assets/mlkit_barcode_models/*.tflite` TensorFlow Lite models are missing.
If it still detects barcode, this may be due to `play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning`.

---

a) For bundling the models with your app (larger package):

```
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.2'
```

b) For using the models from Google Play Services (download on demand):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.0.0'
```

Source: [Scan Barcodes with ML Kit on Android](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android).